# Can I ignore Cora Data warning regarding too many attributes?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4, compiler-warnings, datamodel

I'm using Core Data (with sqlite) in an iOS app and currently adding some new attributes to an entity. I'm up to around 110 attributes. I realise this is a lot, but when I tried to organise the data in a different way I found it impossible to keep my app working reliably.

Xcode is now giving me a warning: "Misconfigured Entity: Entity has more than 100 properties; consider a more shallow entity hierarchy or denormalized properties."

I don't know what it means by denormalized properties, but let's say I'm keen to keep my data model the way it is. I never normally ship code that has any warnings of any sort. But can I safely ignore this warning, at least for the time being until I work out a better way to structure my data?

Comment: Have read up on denormalization. It's basically a term for what I already tried, unsuccessfully, to do with my data model. I'm pretty new to databases, and it seems I can't actually follow what's happening with my data unless it is normalized.

Comment: Can you describe you entity more preciesly?

Comment: The entity is a pupil who has to be graded in 33 different categories. each category has a skill level (string), a date on which it was updated (date) and some notes (string). There are further attributes for the pupil's first name, second name, date of birth, email address, general notes, etc. When the pupil's record is selected, practically all of these pieces of information are displayed at once (ie all of the details except for a couple are handled in one view controller and displayed in the same table view). I'm currently working on an update to the app and want to avoid major changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the Category to a separate entity, that would consist of title, skill level, date and notes. That is the right way, and it will move out all the warnings.
You pupils will have one-to-many relationship with the category—one pupil could be in many categories—that's it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I should do. It'll be a major migration for me; I've only used lightweight migration so far. I would also have to make a lot of code changes. If I keep it the way it is for the next update and then fix the data model in a later update, would it continue to work in the meantime? I know it's not good practice, but this app is ridiculously complicated and I've got customers breathing down my neck for an update that adds more categories (taking it over 100 attributes). I want to get the update out to them ASAP and without rushing the migration, so I can do it carefully.